# `fopen` fails on Windows Server but works on Windows 7 after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fopen, windows-server-2003-r2

We have a mixed Java/JRuby project that uses a C++-DLL developped in Microsoft Visual Studio. Recently, the supplier of this DLL upgraded their development environment to Visual Studio 2015 professional. This required installation of the new runtime libraries (vcredist_x86.exe) on our machines (which are running on Windows 7). After we did this, everything worked as expected.

However, we also use a server (Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2) to run regression tests. I installed the new runtime libraries, and the DLL is loaded. But when the program is run, we get an `fopen` error when the DLL tries to load a certain file. `errno` gives 2 (`ENOENT` according to `errno.h`). The file is present, the DLL tries to load it using a relative path. It is not the first file that is opened via `fopen`, and access to the other files seems to work.

I do not have access to the source and cannot debug on the server and the developers of the DLL cannot reproduce the problem.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem on Windows Server after updating to Visual Studio 2015? And if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Is Windows xp support enabled?

Comment: instead of `fopen`ing the file, try to `fstat` the file and collect information on size, permissioning, etc.

Comment: what is the file and where is it present on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 R2? Is it a system file? has the dll hardcoded the file path?

Comment: @Prab: It is in the same location on both systems. It is a small binary file (744 bytes) with a `.bin` extension. It is not a system file and has read and execute permissions. The DLL has hardcodced the relative path to the file.

Comment: @norisknofun: Since I don't have access to the source, that's difficult. I will ask the developer to provide a new DLL that calls `fstat` and writes the results to a log file.

Comment: @James: Where should that be enabled?

Comment: @Axel Its possible that the containing folder is hidden or is read protected. Before running the dll can you manually modify the permissions on the folder and give `Full Control` to all users

Comment: @Axel In the project's properties, change the toolset to something like "VS2015-xp". May be you need to ask the developer to check it.

Comment: @prab: It is neither hidden nor read protected. I also updated the permissions as you said, but nothing changes.

Comment: @Axel a good way to check things is for you to write a simple dll which tries to open the file. Then you can get back to the Developer with your findings

Answer (score 0):

The supplier of the DLL probably used the default toolset v140 which is not compatible with Server 2003.  If you use Server 2008 for tests I suspect you'll be fine.  Or if they are able to use the v140_xp toolset I suspect you'll be fine.  That option is here: Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset